# How to start a counter at the ThreadNum

Tags: jmeter, counter

I'd like to start my counter at ThreadNum * 1000. So I tried various methods, none of which seem to work. Am I missing something?

e.g.

```
      <CounterConfig guiclass="CounterConfigGui" testclass="CounterConfig" testname="Counter" enabled="true">
        <stringProp name="CounterConfig.start">${__jexl2(ctx.getThreadNum()*1000)}</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="CounterConfig.end">999999</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="CounterConfig.incr">1</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="CounterConfig.name">TOTP</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="CounterConfig.format">000000</stringProp>
        <boolProp name="CounterConfig.per_user">true</boolProp>
        <boolProp name="CounterConfig.reset_on_tg_iteration">true</boolProp>
      </CounterConfig>
```

I am using the counter further down in an HTTP POST as a parameter and can see the parameter is always starting at 000001.

I would use a __counter variable as the POST parameter, but it doesn't look like you can do the preceding zeroes with a __counter.

I tried creating an external variable called START with beanshell :

```
    <BeanShellSampler guiclass="BeanShellSamplerGui" testclass="BeanShellSampler" testname="BeanShell Sampler" enabled="true">
      <stringProp name="BeanShellSampler.query">vars.put (&quot;START&quot;, &quot;0&quot; + ctx.getThreadNum() * 1000 );
</stringProp>
....
<stringProp name="CounterConfig.start">${START}</stringProp>
....
```

That has a preceding zero, and still my counter starts at 000000 despite seeing START values of 01000 and 02000 (if I add ${START} as a parameter in the POST request).

Even simply starting the counter at ${__threadNum} didn't seem to make it start at ThreadNum. Is this a field that won't accept a variable value?

Answer (score -1):

I cannot reproduce your issue using latest [JMeter 4.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-4)

[image: JMeter Counter with Variable and Functions Expression]

JMeter starts with `001000` and continues as `002000`, `003000`, etc.

[image: JMeter Counter start from 1000]

So try upgrading to JMeter 4.0 (or whatever is the latest version available at the [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page) and try on clean latest installation. If it doesn't help - check out if there are any suspicious entries in *jmeter.log* file. Also make sure you have [ApacheJMeter_functions.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jmeter/ApacheJMeter_functions) in "lib/ext" folder of your JMeter installation (or in your project [Classpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java)) if you run JMeter from a Java program)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, I can't reproduce your success on that same version and using the same jexl3 calculation. I can call the sampler ${TOTP} and do a get on /${__jexl3(${__threadNum} * 1000,)} and see each sample called 001000 doing a get on 1000, 2000, 3000, etc....
The "start" values are present/correct. If I put a static value of "500" then it works. But not if the start is a variable...
Could you copy/paste the code for your counter?

Comment: I meant the whole counter, not just the start value, but never mind I think I have discovered the issue...

Comment: Can you try increasing your thread count to 10 and see if the results reliably track from thread number to TOTP value? You should see it start to repeat some. (I think you already are, your first run, both threads 1 and 2 got a TOTP of 001000 and second time both were 002000)

Answer (score -1):

I thought this was an OSX issue.

Both windows are using the same script. Run under OSX on the left,  Windows on the right :

[image: OSX vs Windows]

You can see on the left, most of the TOTP have the same value, when I was first doing this, they would always be the same, everywhere.

On the right, they are the thread number - EXCEPT the highlighted one which re-uses "6" for thread 8. Mostly Windows gets it right, but *sometimes* gets it wrong. WTF??

Running from the command line I see the same problem on both platforms. Sometimes it gets it right, sometimes not, with greater or lesser degrees of success... So I think this is a Jmeter issue!